# Can't get data from asp.net textboxes that have readonly as 'true'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have few asp.net textboxes in a gridview which have readonly="true" and when I try to get value from them it sends null or empty string.These textboxes get value from a multiplication javascript function and I want that value to be saved in database.also, I don't want the user to type in any of those textboxes
Here, is one the textboxes that have readonly as true;

```
<asp:TextBox readonly="true" runat="server" ID="txtSubTotal"></asp:TextBox>
```

and here is the code that gets the value;

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++){
//other textboxes...
sbt = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("txtSubTotal")).Text;
}
```

I've looked at some solutions that have said to write .Attributes.Add("readonly","readonly") on the textbox, but it does not work with my code as it is inside a gridview and a loop.

Any type of help would be appreciated.
THanks!!!

Comment: You should be getting the values regardless of being readonly so the problem is something else. Run the browser dev tools network trace while you make the POST and look at what is in the POST body of the request.

Comment: @Crowcoder Hi, I'm getting values from all the textboxes that don't have readonly as true. But, the ones with readonly are sending null or empty string.

Comment: Can you remove the readonly attribute as a temporary test and see what happens?

Comment: @Crowcoder it works after removing readonly. But I dont want the user to type in the textbox.